# XNA Peer-to-Peer

Tags: networking, xna, client-server, p2p

what is the best way for writing an XNA Peer-to-Peer game **without having to use the Windows Live stuff that requires that both players of the game have an XBOX Gold membership**

I also need some client/server functionality but that isn't as critical yet!

Thank you.

edit: what does everyone think of this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.peertopeer.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifically, the [System.Net.PeerToPeer namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.peertopeer.aspx) should be mentioned here. For client/server functionality you should look for more complete libraries, like [Ice](http://www.zeroc.com/icedotnet.html).

**Update:** I admit to not having actively used these classes (yet), though the statement "capabilities for serverless managed collaboration sessions" and [the classes available in the Collaboration namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.peertopeer.collaboration.aspx) seems to be a promising P2P implementation.

Its worth noting that there seems to be a limitation to running on Vista.

Comment: Yes, I would believe Windows 7 is covered.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the .Net networking classes from the `System.Net` namespace.